# escapeshellarg with UTF-8 only works every other time

Tags: php, shell, unicode, utf-8, locale

```
<?php
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'en_GB.utf8');
echo escapeshellarg("ÅÄÖ");
```

That simple scripts generates `''` `''` `'ÅÄÖ'` `''` `'ÅÄÖ'` when run 5 consecutive times (hitting <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd> 5 times).

I suppose there's a race condition happening, with other page loads interfering. Can I solve this, short of writing my own `escapeshellarg`?

---

Update: Apache running on Linux. `apache2 -V` output:

```
Server version: Apache/2.2.17 (Ubuntu)
Server built:   Nov  3 2011 02:13:53
Server's Module Magic Number: 20051115:25
Server loaded:  APR 1.4.2, APR-Util 1.3.9
Compiled using: APR 1.4.2, APR-Util 1.3.9
Architecture:   64-bit
Server MPM:     Prefork
  threaded:     no
    forked:     yes (variable process count)
Server compiled with....
 -D APACHE_MPM_DIR="server/mpm/prefork"
 -D APR_HAS_SENDFILE
 -D APR_HAS_MMAP
 -D APR_HAVE_IPV6 (IPv4-mapped addresses enabled)
 -D APR_USE_SYSVSEM_SERIALIZE
 -D APR_USE_PTHREAD_SERIALIZE
 -D SINGLE_LISTEN_UNSERIALIZED_ACCEPT
 -D APR_HAS_OTHER_CHILD
 -D AP_HAVE_RELIABLE_PIPED_LOGS
 -D DYNAMIC_MODULE_LIMIT=128
 -D HTTPD_ROOT="/etc/apache2"
 -D SUEXEC_BIN="/usr/lib/apache2/suexec"
 -D DEFAULT_PIDLOG="/var/run/apache2.pid"
 -D DEFAULT_SCOREBOARD="logs/apache_runtime_status"
 -D DEFAULT_LOCKFILE="/var/run/apache2/accept.lock"
 -D DEFAULT_ERRORLOG="logs/error_log"
 -D AP_TYPES_CONFIG_FILE="mime.types"
 -D SERVER_CONFIG_FILE="apache2.conf"
```

Comment: Sure, just write it your own.

Comment: So short of writing my own `escapeshellarg`, you suggest I write my own? ;-) The original function is 60 lines of C code, there has to be another solution then make my own possibly flawed and insecure version.

Comment: [use your computer](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php#refsect1-function.setlocale-notes)

Comment: @hakre I updated the question. This is not a multi-threaded Apache build

Comment: Which SAPI is PHP using with that MPM pre-forked httpd?

Comment: [`php_sapi_name`](http://php.net/php_sapi_name), also part of `phpinfo`.

Comment: If you remove the `setlocale` command, how does your script behave?

Comment: The [PHP doc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php) mentions:

The locale information is maintained per process, not per thread. If you are running PHP on a multithreaded server API , you may experience sudden changes in locale settings while a script is running, though the script itself never called setlocale(). This happens due to other scripts running in different threads of the same process at the same time, changing the process-wide locale using setlocale(). Maybe that's related.